# Determine which command-line argument is given based on value in Rust (e.g. using Clap)

Tags: rust, command-line-interface, clap

I am building a CLI utility in Rust. For simplicity, let's say that it executes a task given as a command-line argument. The user can also *optionally* specify, through arguments, who requested the task ("Engineering" or "HR", say) and the priority of the task ("high" or "low").

I would want the program to recognize which argument is being specified from the values alone, i.e. without command line flags. (The possible values of the arguments do not overlap.) So for example, these should all work:

```
app task1 HR

app task2 high

app task3 low Engineering

app task4 high HR
```

Of course, I can write custom logic for this, but my question is: can I do this using a crate for parsing command-line arguments, such as *clap*?

Fwiw, I have tried to get this behaviour using the `ArgGroup` struct from the *clap*, but with no success. So:

```
use clap::{App,Arg,ArgGroup};

fn main() {

let m = App::new("app")
    .arg(Arg::with_name("task_name")
        .required(true))
    .arg(Arg::with_name("requested_by")
        .possible_values(&["HR","Engineering"])
        .required(false))
    .arg(Arg::with_name("priority")
        .possible_values(&["high","low"])
        .required(false))
    .group(ArgGroup::with_name("options")
        .arg("requested_by")
        .arg("priority")
        .multiple(true))
    .get_matches_from(vec!["app", "task1","high"]);
}
```

This insists on parsing "high" as a `requested_by`, rather than as a `priority`, so it gives:

> error: 'high' isn't a valid value for '<requested_by>'
> [possible values: Engineering, HR]
>
> USAGE:
> app <task_name> <requested_by|priority>
>
> For more information try --help

Comment: I thinks that "clap" is designed for standard usage and what you want do is not very standard. You have to use the standard env::Args `use std::env; let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();`

Comment: Why not just use a standard CLI design instead of one that will be confusing and error prone?

Comment: Thanks, Zeppi, as I suspected. As for my reason to prefer this design, I was thinking that it would be a bit more ergonomic, since the tool is mostly for myself, and I expect to use it often. What do you think the biggest problem with it is, Herohtar?